# Manual function inside query?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, lumen

Is there any way to put a manual function inside a query in Laravel.

I've timestamp saved in string in DB. I want to convert timestamp from one timezone to another. All the timestamp is inserted in one time zone, and depending upon my user I fetch the timestamp and convert it into their timezone.

what I want to achieve is something like this..

```
$query = BlogCategory::select('merchant_id', userTime(added_at))              
                        ->where('site_id', $site_id)
                        ->get();
```

userTime() function takes two parameter, the timestamp and the timezone and converts the timsestamp to time of the user.

I want to use userTime() function before fetching the data. I dont want to fetch the data first and then do foreach and so on.

I know I might be absolutely absurd but is there anything of this sort in Laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can achieved that using collection map

```
$query = BlogCategory::select('merchant_id', 'added_at')              
                        ->where('site_id', $site_id)
                        ->get();

$dateAdded = $query->map(function ($data) {
    // try this if error $data['merchant_id']
    return array(
       'merchant_id' => $data->merchant_id,
       'added_at' => $this->userTime($data->added_at)
   );
})

dd($dateAdded);
```

Read Collection documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `selectRaw` statement and let your DB do this logic for you if you don't want to loop over the result set.

For example if your underlying database is MySQL you can use the `CONVERT_TIMEZONE` function and do something like this.

```
BlogCategory::selectRaw('merchant_id, CONVERT_TZ(added_at, "GMT", "MET") as added_at')              
                    ->where('site_id', $site_id)
                    ->get();
```

Comment: Your solution looks good, Can I convert one timestamp(All in one time zone) to another timezone , eg- Asia/Kolkata to Europe/London ?